# Excel for Mac - Cells containing user-defined functions won't update

Tags: macos, worksheet-function, vba

I'm working on some VBA code that writes formulas containing user-defined functions (UDFs) into certain cells of my workbook,  e.g.: H1004 `= maxdd(H1:H1001)`.

When I run the code in **Excel 2010 (for Windows)** everything works as expected:

1) the formulas are written into the cells
2) each cell returns the correct result.

When I run the same code in **Excel 2011 for Mac** the formulas will also be written into the cells. However, the cells won't return any valid results - instead they display `#value` errors.

**Note:**   I can't troubleshoot this issue because when I select one of these cells, put the cursor in the formula field, and press return (presumably forcing the cell to evaluate), the correct answer appears.

---

**My question:**

- What needs to be done to keep Excel for Mac from returning `#value` errors instead of the plain results?

Comment: I'm unsure if this could cause problems for your project (without knowing the details of what you're doing), but you could try adding `Application.Volatile` to the start of your function's VBA code. This will cause Excel to recalculate the UDFs every time the sheet is recalculated.

Comment: @Excellll I've already tried ``Application.Volatile`` and ``Application.CalculateFull``...it still gave me the errors.

Comment: Try to do the operations in your maxdd function one by one on Mac to see which operation is causing the value error.

Comment: @Joop The maxdd function itself is flawless - when I type it into a cell manually, the cell will return the correct result immediately. The #value errors only appear when I let the vba code "type" it into the cells.  
Also: there can't really be an error in the vba code, since the same procedure works perfectly on Windows.

Comment: Can you post some sample code of the maxdd code so we can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out *what* caused this problem, although I have no idea *why* it caused the problem:

In order to make the vba code run faster, I had turned off `automatic calculation` at the beginning of the code and turned it back on at the end of the code, just like this -->

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  
'main part of vba code
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

For some reason, this kept the cells containing user-defined functions from being updated.
Without these two lines of code everything works fine now.